# Lombok annotation and jdbcOperation

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, lombok

I have a bean:

```
@Data
class Sample {
    @NonNull
    private final String name,
    @NonNull
    private final String rollNumber,
    @NonNull
    private final String standard,
}
```

I am saving this bean data to database in the table `sample`.
The problem:
I am using `jdbcOperation` to fetch data from the database. In my use case I want to retrieve only two fields from the database say `name` and `standard` for a particular view(I'm using Spring MVC). As all the three fields in the bean are marked with `NonNull` annotation from `Lombok`, I can not create an object inside the `RowMapper` overriden implementation.

```
private static final class SampleRowMapper implements RowMapper<Sample> {

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public Sample mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {


        Sample sample =
                    new Sample(
                            rs.getString("name"),
                            rs.getString("standard")
                            null); // error as annotation doesn't allow null values
        return sample;
    }
}
```

If I remove the annotation there are other cases that will be missed out(say saving an object of `Sample` with no null values, I don't want `rollNumber` to be null). What should be done to fulfill all use cases?

Comment: Create a new object.

Comment: Why not create a new class only for the View?

Comment: there can be multiple views, this is just a simplified version of the actual code, can't create a bean for every needed view

Comment: can you not use `""` instead of null?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe this is the last option for me. Any other cleaner way ?

Comment: Eh, that seems fairly clean to me. Could pontentially look into a lombok `@Builder` https://reinhard.codes/2016/07/13/using-lomboks-builder-annotation-with-default-values/ with `@Builder.Default` etc. but to me that's adding a lot of complexity vs. just using `""`.

Comment: Get rid of `@NotNull` and use database not null constraints

Comment: @NicoVanBelle Annotation and db level constraints serve their own purposes.

Comment: So if I understand well you want some kind of validation (i.e. field not null) but only in some cases that you cannot express by code (i.e. using some new "view"), I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: That is an instance create a new class (which is what I actually intended to say). Something like a `SampleView` or whatever.

Comment: @RC I have given two scenarios, both are equally possible and valid. Validation for not null, yes I need that but I don't want to check explicitly using if and else. That's where these annotations are lot helpful. The most important thing is they generate warnings when a developer is writing the code. Ex. you are calling toString() on a null value, the annotation will help get rid of this while writing code and before this fails in live production code

Comment: Let's try again: you have some machine, when you put 1$ in it it gives you a soda. Now I want that machine to give water instead in some cases. I cannot tell you what cases but I want it to work automatically. That's what you ask (or I didn't understand). Lombok `@NonNull` cannot guess in what *use case* we are at some moment

Comment: @RC I know machine won't dispense water, hence the OP :D